# GameCenter framework image not found error for Xcode 7.0 Beta 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7-beta4

Does anyone face this issue when trying to run their application on an actual iPhone (iOS version 8.4) using Xcode 7 Beta 4?

> dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/GameCenter.framework/GameCenter
>     Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CC713E5A-7839-43F1-9AEB-932AE2A3DF8A/....
>     Reason: image not found

For your information, it has been working with no errors before I switch to Xcode 7...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is gone in XCode Beta 5. Somebody to confirm this?

Comment: Hi sorry, I was away for the last few days for my country's jubilee weekend and had not been coding. Yes, it has been resolved with Xcode 7 beta 5. There is no need to make the changes shared in this thread :)

Answer (score 2):

In Project Settings->Build Settings weak link both the new iOS 9 GameCenter lib and the old GameKit libs and try again. You can weak link them by specifying the 'Status' as 'Optional'.

[image]

You need the old one still incase you're running on an older iOS than 9 which will need the GameKit stub library linked in still as it won't know about the new GameCenter one for iOS 9.

It may also be necessary to change

```
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
```

to

```
#import <GameCenter/GameCenter.h>
```

If I had to guess the change might simply be down to using a less generic library name as Apple continue to add more game orientated libs (Spritekit, Scenekit, Replaykit etc), renaming the main GameCenter lib from GameKit to GameCenter makes sense.

Comment: Sorry... could you explain how to weak link both the new iOS 9 GameCenter lib and the old GameKit libs? I currently only see the new GameCenter lib which is needed for the application to compile without error i.e. import GameCenter. How do you support both? If I am running on iOS 8.4, then how do I specify the old GameKit stub library? Thank you.

Comment: Do the added details explain well enough and does the answer solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It does resolve the issue! :D The problem now is that it still crash because I need the iOS 8 way of handling Game Center (it crash at         let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer)... I believe this means that I need to check 'if #available(iOS 9, *)' and code separately. Now it makes me wonder it is worthwhile to support iOS 8 at the same time...

Comment: Perhaps something similar to:
`NSString
    *iOSVersionrequired = @"4.1",
    *iOSVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
  
  bool osVersionSupported = ([iOSVersion compare:iOSVersionrequired options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending);`

If a runtime check is better.

Would you please accept the answer above if it's all good?

Comment: Sorry...
 
I have an runtime error at
 
        let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer()
 
The error is:
 
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code = 1, address = 0x20)
 
 
P.S.: I have no errors with iOS 9 but with iOS 8.4. By the way, I've import GameCenter.
 
Do you happen to know what is happening?

Comment: Sorry @LFS I haven't actually got that far myself, I only needed to get my projects building for the time being. I'd recommend creating a separate question to attract answers for that specific issue.

Comment: Could you more clearly elaborate on the reasoning as to what is going on here?  Has GameCenter replaced GameKit binaries?

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked well on iOS 8.4 and iOS 9 with these modifications to the above suggestions:

- Don't change your code, just stick with **#import < GameKit/GameKit.h >**
- When building with XCode 7, add GameCenter.framework (weak link / optional) and
  don't change this option for the GameKit.framework (required)

That's it.

If XCode7 gives you a linker error about GameKit.Framework, go back to XCode 6.4 and rebuild the project (disable the target membership of GameCenter.framework in the file inspector before). Then go back to XCode 7 - the linker error is gone.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean that you totally do not change the codes from Swift/Objective-C to Swift2?

Comment: I won't be able to rebuild the project in Xcode 6.4 because I've converted all of them to Swift 2.0... I think there is a bug with the new Game Center?

Comment: No worries :) Wine's better when it's old yeah?

Comment: This solved the problem for me (Xcode 7 Beta 4) with an objective c app. I did not have to go back to Xcode 6.4.