# GKLocalPlayer runtime error for iOS 8.4 with Xcode 7 Beta 4

Tags: ios, game-center, swift2, xcode7-beta4

This is a follow-up to [my last question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779111/gamecenter-framework-image-not-found-error-for-xcode-7-0-beta-4). I did as advised to weak link both GameCenter and GameKit libraries, and imported GameCenter. However, I still cannot start my application on an actual iPhone (iOS version 8.4).

The runtime error happens at:

```
let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer()
```

The error is:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code = 1, address = 0x20)

P.S.: I have no errors with the iOS 9 simulator that comes with Xcode 7 Beta 4.

Anyone knows if this is a bug with Xcode 7 beta 4 or there is a solution?

Thank you for your attention.